# Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy my app on AWS but it seems to stuck at this point:

```
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2019-10-22 11:01:57    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2019-10-22 11:02:00    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-10-22 11:02:09    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2019-10-22 11:02:10    ERROR   [Instance: i-#######] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-10-22 11:02:10    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-10-22 11:02:10    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i########'. Aborting the operation.
2019-10-22 11:02:11    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

It says that my requirements.txt is invalid, Why ?

Requirement.txt

```
Django
django-crispy-forms==1.7.0
pytz==2017.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
django-widget-tweaks
psycopg2
```

Please help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The error message says "Snapshot your logs for details". What do the logs say?

Comment: It also says `For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI`